# How to run a Linux script(already added to the $PATH) from Java?

Tags: java, shell

I'm trying to run a script with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, but nothing happens. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Here's `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "It works"
```

I have added the sh file's location to the PATH because I don't want to hard code it's location. In the terminal both the above script works from any location(directory):

```
$ script.sh
It works
```

But not via Java:

```
$ javac Test.java && java Test
done
```

This is what I expected:

```
$ javac Test.java && java Test
It works
done
```

Why don't I get the script's output, or at least an error message?

Comment: What kind of response do you get?

Comment: No error message. Nothing happened.

Comment: How are you testing whether "nothing happened"? Do you expect output to be written to the TTY? Are you looking at the operating system's process table to see if the program you started is present? Are you looking at the `Process` object returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`? Providing a [mcve] that let someone else see your problem by running code you provide in the question would answer all these questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry about your rough first experience: people tend to downvote questions that don't contain sufficient information. I edited yours, added complete source code to reproduce, the actual output, and the expected output. It's now easier to see what the problem is, both for people who answer and for future readers with the same issue. Consider following the same format for your next question!

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot *that other guy*(how to tag people?). Hi *Charles Duffy*, the normal output is the running of a program like gedit for example. When I specify the absolute path in the java code the script executes, thus I know there is supposed to be a program running on successful execution of the script. Which doesn't happen if I run the above code.

Comment: Can you edit the example to show your problem then (and make sure to run the code from your own post to ensure it's captured the problem)? One great piece of information is to run `env` from Java to show the PATH. Maybe it doesn't contain the dir you expected for some reason, or maybe it contains an invalid `~`

Comment: @AbidAbdullah, ...so, that other guy gave us an example that someone else can run themselves to see the problem with their own eyes (albeit apparently a different problem than you intended to ask about). Can you do that here, making the example stand-alone and complete enough that people don't have to guess at what your problem is? Keep in mind that for a graphical program like gedit to work, environment variables describing how to connect to the X server need to be present; if your Java program is started in a way that doesn't have those variables, well, there you are.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for ensuring that any data the command writes to stdout or stderr is surfaced in your application.

If you don't explicitly do anything, messages will not be shown anywhere. Instead they'll be stuck in a pipe buffer somewhere. Here's your example without the `script.sh` dependency, using `ls` as an example to write both output and errors:

```
$ ls -d /tmp /doesntexist
ls: /doesntexist: No such file or directory
/tmp

$ cat Test.java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -d /tmp /doesntexist");
    }
}

$ javac Test.java && java Test
(no output)
```

If you simply want to show output and errors on the terminal where you run your Java program, let the process inherit Java's stdout/stderr:

```
$ cat Test.java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-d", "/tmp", "/doesntexist");
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectError (ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.start();
    }
}

$ javac Test.java && java Test
ls: /doesntexist: No such file or directory
/tmp
```

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying. But my problem is not that, please read my comment to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Process API

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("sh", "script.sh");
Process process = builder.start();
```

update
try to add environment manually (just for now)

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    builder.command("sh", "script.sh");
    Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
    env.put("PATH", "/yourpath/");
    Process process = builder.start();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same result, nothing happens, no error.

Comment: This defeats my purpose of not hardcoding the path, in the manual of my software I will tell the user to add the location of the script to their path variable, which will be machine dependent

Comment: I suggested that to isolate and make sure that problem is indeed in environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can your environment see the new PATH you set?
You can check with:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("sh", "printenv";
Process process = builder.start();
```

If not, where are you setting the PATH variable from? It sounds like a terminal window, which does not update your environment variables universally.

Try to export the path, then run an executable JAR of your program from the same shell:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/script.sh
java -jar program.jar
```

If you are running from an IDE, you can set the PATH variable and run the IDE from the same terminal instance.

Have you tried running with the full path of the script first?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

`runtime.getruntime().exec("sh -c script.sh");`

Might not be necessarily an issue pertaining to java, sometimes linux acts weird.

Comment: If you can pass `sh -c something` as a single string (vs three separate strings in an array), there's a shell breaking the `sh`, `-c`, and `script.sh` into separate arguments. If you have a shell already running, starting an additional one adds no value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Haha, I wish! `.exec(String)` actually splits the command on spaces using plain Java string operations. Some poor Sun engineer probably thought it would be helpful and cross-platform, and people have struggled with it ever since.

Comment: ...ugh. *Ugh*. I now know a little more, but also have less faith in the world.

Comment: Lol, sorry didn't know that's what Java does. Just applying the fact that when scripts sometime don't run it helps to create a new shell in Linux.

Comment: @KavinthaKulasingham, if that's true, the better way to fix it is to repair the script -- if a script can be started by a shell but not by a non-shell program, that generally means it either doesn't have a valid shebang (that the first line isn't `#!/bin/bash` or similar) or doesn't have `+x` permissions set.